# android, null pointer of 1 class when trying to open same pop-up from another object

Tags: java, android

Sorry because I am coming with stupid questions, is my first time here.I will try first to explain my application.
I have 3 objects ( or 3 java class in android ) Every class is basically an ImageView with a textView ( first 2 class, the last class is only an Imageview ).I succeed to open the same Pop-up where I change values of the text views or doing other stuffs.
So basically I have 3 images views with fiew text views where I want to open the same pop-up and change some values of the textViews or changing some backgrounds etc.I have implemented this only for 2 classes and when I open the pop-up from 1 object I get null to Other one, same to second object when I open it I get Null Pointer at first object.I will put some commented lines of my code below:

MainActivity:

```
                RelativeLayout mylayout; //Getting my Layout
                mylayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
                RelativeLayout inflator = new RelativeLayout(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
                inflator.setLayoutParams(lp);
                mylayout.addView(inflator);
                inflator.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

                TemperatureSymbol mytempsymbol = new TemperatureSymbol(getActivity(), inflator);
                HumiditySymbol myhumiditysymbol = new HumiditySymbol(getActivity(), inflator);
```

Ok, in mainActivity I am creating the objects and  add them to a layout, I want those object to stick together in a tiny layout and move only the layout, inflator is the layout where I am adding them.

TemperatureSymbol.class

```
public class TemperatureSymbol extends LinearLayout{
        private int[] location = new int[2];
        private ImageView temperature;
        private int value = 20;
        private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
        private ControlListener controlListener;
        private TextView celsius;


        public interface ControlListener {
            public void onLongStatement();
        }

        public void setControlListener(ControlListener controlListener) {
            this.controlListener = controlListener;
        }


        public TemperatureSymbol getSymbol(){
            return this;
        }

void setValue(int counter){
    value = counter;
    celsius.setText("" + value + "°C");
}//THIS IS IMPORTANT BECAUSE WITH THIS METHOD I SET THE VALUE ON TextView WHEN I INCREMENT/DECREMENT A BUTTON

        public TemperatureSymbol(Context context, RelativeLayout inflator) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        temperature = (ImageView) new ImageView(context);
        temperature.setBackgroundResource(drawable.termometruoff);
        celsius = new TextView(context);

        inflator.addView(temperature);
        celsius.setText("°C");
        inflator.addView(celsius);

        inflator.getLocationOnScreen(location); 

       //Gather informations for GestureListener
        MyGestureListener gestList = new MyGestureListener(location, context, inflator);
        gestList.setTemperatureSymbol(this);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, gestList);

         temperature.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                Log.i("TEST","Simple touch");
                return true;

            }
        });

    }

}
```

TemperatureSymbol.class is one of my object, basically is only an ImageView with a textview where to display a value like: 20 degrees Celsius.Basically the HumiditySymbol.class is the same as Temperature, same textview same ImageView only the image are changed.

Below is myGestureListener class where I open the same pop-up window from both objects.

```
class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {



    // Handler that is used for OnLongPress to Continue Decrementin/Incrementing Value
    public class RptUpdater implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            if (mAutoIncrement && tvalue < 35) {
                increment();
                repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new RptUpdater(), REP_DELAY);
            } else if (mAutoDecrement && tvalue > 10) {
                decrement();
                repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new RptUpdater(), REP_DELAY);
            }
        }

        private void decrement() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (tvalue > 10) {
                tvalue--;
                localTempSymbol.setValue(tvalue);
                }
            }

        private void increment() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (tvalue < 35) {
                tvalue++;
                localTempSymbol.setValue(tvalue);
        }
    }

    // Handler that is used for OnLongPress
    public class RptUpdaterHumidity implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            if (mAutoIncrementHumidity && hvalue < 100) {
                increment();
                repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new RptUpdaterHumidity(),
                        REP_DELAY);
            } else if (mAutoDecrementHumidity && hvalue > 0) {
                decrement();
                repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new RptUpdaterHumidity(),
                        REP_DELAY);
            }
        }

        private void decrement() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hvalue > 0) {
                hvalue--;
                localHumSymbol.setHumidity(hvalue);
            }
        }

        private void increment() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hvalue < 100) {
                hvalue++;
                localHumSymbol.setHumidity(hvalue);
        }

    }


    public void setTemperatureSymbol(TemperatureSymbol tempSymbol) {
        localTempSymbol = tempSymbol;
    }

    public void setHumiditySymbol(HumiditySymbol tempSymbol) {
        localHumSymbol = tempSymbol;
    }



    public MyGestureListener(int[] showLocation, Context context,
            RelativeLayout inflator) {
        super();

        add = new Button(context);
        sub = new Button(context);
        addH = new Button(context);
        subH = new Button(context);
        popUp = new PopupWindow(context);
        popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new ShapeDrawable());
        popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
                android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout.addView(add);
        layout.addView(sub);
        layout.addView(addH);
        layout.addView(subH);


        popUp.setContentView(layout);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (tvalue < maxTvalue) {
                    tvalue++;
                    localTempSymbol.setValue(tvalue);
                }

            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (tvalue > minTvalue) {
                    tvalue--;
                    Log.i("TEST", "localTemp = " + localTempSymbol);
                    localTempSymbol.setValue(tvalue);
                }
            }
        });

        // Long click listener to enable the value to increment
        add.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mAutoIncrement = true;
                repeatUpdateHandler.post(new RptUpdater());
                return false;
            }
        });
        add.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event
                        .getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                        && mAutoIncrement)
                    mAutoIncrement = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Long click listener to enable the value to decrement
        sub.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mAutoDecrement = true;
                repeatUpdateHandler.post(new RptUpdater());
                return false;
            }
        });
        sub.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event
                        .getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                        && mAutoDecrement)
                    mAutoDecrement = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

        addH.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (hvalue < 100) {
                    hvalue++;
                    localHumSymbol.setHumidity(hvalue);
                }

            }
        });

        subH.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (hvalue > 0) {
                    hvalue--;
                    Log.i("TEST", "localTemp = " + localHumSymbol);
                    localHumSymbol.setHumidity(hvalue);
                }
            }
        });

        // Long click listener to enable the value to increment
        addH.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mAutoIncrementHumidity = true;
                repeatUpdateHandlerHumidity.post(new RptUpdaterHumidity());
                return false;
            }
        });
        addH.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event
                        .getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                        && mAutoIncrementHumidity)
                    mAutoIncrementHumidity = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Long click listener to enable the value to decrement
        subH.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mAutoDecrementHumidity = true;
                repeatUpdateHandlerHumidity.post(new RptUpdaterHumidity());
                return false;
            }
        });
        subH.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event
                        .getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                        && mAutoDecrementHumidity)
                    mAutoDecrementHumidity = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
        //Here I read in logcat for example if I open the pop-up from TemperatureSymbol that Humidity is null
        popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, 10, 10);
        popUp.update(location[0], location[1], LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    }
}
```

I have this problem from days and I couldn't find a solution, the only Ideea I had is to change the values through setter method of every symbol.I don't want to do everywhint in one class, I just want to keep them like this but get rid of null pointer.

UPDATE:

When I am running the application, open the pop-up from first Symbol and trying to modify the Second:

```
10-30 09:35:17.583: I/TEST(12117): localTemp = com.example.symbol_temp_med.TemperatureSymbol{4246d188 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
10-30 09:35:21.997: I/TEST(12117): localTemp = null
10-30 09:35:21.997: D/AndroidRuntime(12117): Shutting down VM
10-30 09:35:21.997: W/dalvikvm(12117): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b72ba8)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117): Process: com.example.symbol_temp_med, PID: 12117
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at com.example.symbol_temp_med.MyGestureListener$9.onClick(MyGestureListener.java:348)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-30 09:35:22.007: E/AndroidRuntime(12117):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error line indicate herE:

```
localHumSymbol.setHumidity(hvalue);
```

Comment: Please show the stacktracw of the npe

Comment: I have added the logcat, thank you, hope this is what you needed.

Comment: where is localHumSymbol defined? It is null so make sure you set some value to it.

Comment: it is global, in the GestureListener Class:  private TemperatureSymbol localTempSymbol;
 private HumiditySymbol localHumSymbol;

Comment: @bart I need them in single classes each because I want to add to a view how many I want from each